# Django ModelForm error 'this is a required field'

Tags: django, modelform

When trying to upload an Image in my Django App, I get the error "This is a required field". Even though I am actually uploading an Image. It works fine in the Admin, but not in the App itself. Here is the models.py, forms.py and the View, respectively.

```
models.py
class Blog(models.Model):
    BLOG_CATEGORIES = (
        ( 'T', 'Technology'),
        ( 'B', 'Business' ),
        ( 'C', 'Culture' ),
        ( 'N', 'None' )
    blogger = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.Cascade)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog_post = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    blog_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BLOG_CATEGORIES
    blog_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    blog_picture_context = models.ImageField(upload_to='/static/homepage/', max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} created this entry on {}'.format(self.blogger, self.date_added)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} created this entry on {}'.format(self.blogger, self.date_added)

forms.py
class BLogForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['blogger', 'date_added', 'blog_post', 'blog_category', 'blog_name', 'blog_picture_context']

views.py
class BlogView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'blog_form.html'
    form_class = BlogForm
    success_url = '/'
    login_url = 'users/login/'
```

Again, just for context, I am trying to do this in the app with the development server running. It gives me the error just above the ImageField.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2171.png

Comment: How about the template?

Comment: It simply has the `{% csrf_token %}` and the `{{ form.as_p }}` variable.

Comment: Do you have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form element?

Comment: Yes, and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following in your Form template:

multipart/form-data - required so the server can perceive it as a file and let it upload.

Comment: I have this included, and it still gives the same error.

Comment: I see you are using Formview, but otherwise if its a normal view, adding "request.FILES" to the form class initializer is required when dealing with files. 

eg:
form = BLogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)